# Grocery Crud Relation

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

```
CREATE TABLE `il` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `il_adi` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ilce` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `il_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ilce_adi` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've 2 tables about City - State. **ilce.il_id** relation with **il.id** what I mean,

```
SELECT * FROM il JOIN ilce ON il.id = ilce.il_id
```

How can I do this with Grocery Crud relations? How can I change set_relation function?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14280604/1581368). My answer is:

It is not possible to do this directly, as stated in this [forum post](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/264-join-tables/#entry1018) by the author:

> Actually perhaps it seems obvious to grocery CRUD to have joins and customs queries to the table, but it still NOT an available feature at this moment.

His suggestion is to use the [set_model](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_model) function, which allows to perform the desired SELECT/JOIN by extending the grocery_CRUD_Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a view with your query, set primary key and use set relation.