# Grocery CRUD Join table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Need some help to make a relationship between products and quantity.

```
Table1: Products
Columns: id , code, unit, name, size , cost , price
```

-

```
Table2: qty_products
Columns: id , product_id , warehouse_id , quantity
```

the relation between products here is `id` from `products` and `product_id` from `qty_products`

a simple query for this result is:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, p.unit, p.name, p.size, p.cost, p.price, s.quantity, s.warehouse_id FROM products p
INNER JOIN qty_products s ON s.product_id = p.id
```

this result i need to translate to Grocery CRUD.

```
function products()
    {
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud->set_table('products');
$crud->set_relation('column','table','column');
$output = $crud->render();
$this->_products($output);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Grocery CRUD doesn't support yet the option to join a new table, so i resolved it creating a new model, see result and solution here.

[Link to solution](http://grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1181-how-can-insert-mutiple-items)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this directly, as stated in this [forum post](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/264-join-tables/#entry1018) by the author:

> Actually perhaps it seems obvious to grocery CRUD to have joins and customs queries to the table, but it still NOT an available feature at this moment.

His suggestion is to use the [set_model](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_model) function, which allows to perform the desired SELECT/JOIN by extending the grocery_CRUD_Model.

Comment: Hello, yes, Grocery CRUD doesn't support yet the option to join a new table, so i resolved it creating a new model, see result and solution here. http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1181-how-can-insert-mutiple-items/

Comment: Well done, **Dar**. Nice and clear. Maybe you should copy your exemple here (answering your own question) and then accept your answer. This way, the question would appear as solved, in case anyone else looks for it.

Comment: @Dar isnt this question/answer outdated?